# Bouncing glitch on the Y axis in HTML5 Javascript Game

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, game-physics

in the following code I'm trying to replicate some kind of the brick breaker game for Blackberry on Canvas and HTML 5. I created some classes in order to separate my code in a organized way so it coul be clear to everyone.

Initial vector class:

```
class Vector {
constructor(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
getLength(){
    return Math.sqrt(this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y);
}
```

Ball class:

```
class Ball extends Rect{
constructor(x, y, w, h){
    super(x, y);
    this.vel = new Vector(0, 0);
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}

update(){
    this.x += this.vel.x;
    this.y += this.vel.y;
}
```

Rectangle class:

```
class Rect extends Vector{
contructor(x, y, w, h){
    this.pos = new Vector(x,y);
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}

getLeft(){
    return this.x;
}

getRight(){
    return this.x + this.w;
}

getTop(){
    return this.y;
}

getBottom(){
    return this.y + this.h;
}

static collition(player, ball){
    return (player.getLeft()  < ball.getRight() && player.getRight() > ball.getLeft() 
            && player.getTop() < ball.getBottom() && player.getBottom() > ball.getTop());
}

static collitionX(player, ball){
    return player.getLeft() < ball.getRight() && player.getRight() > ball.getLeft() 
}
static collitionY(player, ball){
    return player.getTop() < ball.getBottom() && player.getBottom() > ball.getTop(); 
}
```

As you can see, first in the main JS file I create instances of the classes and draw them on the canvas with the fillRect() method and add the bouncing so the ball it's wrapped inside the canvas with this code:

```
if(ball.getRight() > canvas.width || ball.getLeft() < 0){
    ball.vel.x = -ball.vel.x;
}

if(ball.getTop() < 0 || ball.getBottom() > canvas.height){
    ball.vel.y = -ball.vel.y;
}
```

Then I chek my collisions with this method:

```
    static collition(player, ball){
    return (player.getLeft()  < ball.getRight() && player.getRight() > ball.getLeft() 
            && player.getTop() < ball.getBottom() && player.getBottom() > ball.getTop());
}
```

That is a pretty normal collision test for rectangles, jus checks if the sides are colliding.

I'll add a snippet so you can see the code properly. The main problem here is that the game detects the collitions perfectly but given that I want to recreate a bouncing effect, everytime the ball hits a side if changes its speed in the X axis, and works perfectly but to prevent the ball from entering the rectangles I need to invert the speed on the Y axis aswell but if I do that the movement gets affected and creates an anormal bouncing effect. So the main question is: How to prevent this from happening without getting the bouncing effect affected, and with prevent I mean prevent the ball from getting inside the rectangles.

I already discovered that to create a X axis bouncing effect, I need to reverse the X speed only, and to create a Y axis one I need to reverse the Y speed only. But changing both at the same time affects the bouncing effect.

Complete snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/95exq760/2/

Comment: The issue with the way you're doing things now is that you don't account for which side of the block the ball is hitting. If you hit the left or right of the block, you should invert the X speed, and if you hit the top or bottom of the block, you should invert the Y speed - not both.

Comment: Then how do I check for individual axes collition? Because all the algorithms I've thinked and found on the internet implements both.

Comment: You don't need to do any more fancy collision detection, you just need to determine where the ball is in relation to the block. See [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/22612) from Game Development Stack Exchange - seems to be exactly what you're looking for :) There's also another answer which shows a more robust way of detecting the angles using vector math, but that might be overcomplicating things in your case.

Comment: Yes, the code is similar to the one I'm using but if I use that it will detect the X collision correctly but even if the ball is waaay below or above the brick? Lets say the brick is at (2,10),  it will detect a collision at (2,20) or at (2,-10). That's why I was forced to use both of axis detections.

Comment: You don't need to use the collision code from the question I linked - use the collision code you already have, and if the ball collides with a block, then you would run some kind of logic to determine where the ball is in relation to the block. The code from the answer I linked might not work exactly (you might have to adjust it to work with your hitboxes/origin points), but the idea will be the same.

Comment: I'd encourage you to Google 'breakout collision physics', there's a lot of good resources on the ways you can implement this, and they'll probably explain it better than I can :)

Comment: I've found something that might work on google, I have to change a couple things but it should improve. Thanks anyway :)